# bootstrap & Normalize.css: spacing problems

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Bootstrap normalize does not seem to remove top and left/right spacing from theme i am developing. Could somebody give hint where is the problem in my code. I have tried several reset css files also without any effects.

Index

```
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<!-- GOOGLE FONTS -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!-- /GOOGLE  FONTS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/flaticon.css">     

<!--do not edit-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<!-- do not edit-->

<!-- add override css here-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyle.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- Favicons  ================================================== -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
```

topbar-content

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGJaVb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I see you have this style

```
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

Try to remove the border style. It should help you.

Comment: That was answer but now i have another: ghost padding 40px from left side of navigation. Any ideas where this comes:
   http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPjrgJ